# Flutter Application with Odoo Backend

Tags: flutter, dart, odoo, flutter-dependencies

I want to develop an application with odoo backend. I have worked on the rest api's earlier which have get . post , put methods and mostly we use http or dio package for integrating the api's.

But in odoo we have rpc calls and i have get to know about odoo_rpc package which is moreover a connection and authentication between odoo and flutter.

My question is that : Is is a good practice to call rpc methods in flutter again and again for developing an app like ecommerce. I have never used odoo before please suggest me a solution. How can i get endpoints like in http: eg: domainname/api/authentication

Refering code:

```
try {
      final session = await client.authenticate('database_name', _username, _password);
      final res = await client.callKw({
        'model': 'res.partner',
        'method': 'search_read',
        'args': [],
        'kwargs': {
          'context': {'bin_size': true},
          'domain': [],
          'fields': [ 'name', 'email'],
          'limit': 80,
        }});
      log('Installed modules: \n' + res.toString());
      print('session$session');
      final response = await client.checkSession();
      print('response$response');
      Future<void> printSessionResult() async {
        var sessionResult = await client.checkSession();
        print('Session Result: $sessionResult');
      }
      printSessionResult();
      void sessionChanged(OdooSession sessionId) async {
        print('We got new session ID: ${sessionId.id}');
        // write to persistent storage
      }

      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
      dataList = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(res);
      // for (var data in dataList) {
      //   print('{id: ${data['id']}, name: ${data['name']}, email: ${data['email']}}');
      // }
      log(dataList.toString());
      Provider.of<DataProvider>(context, listen: false).setDataList(dataList);
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/get_data');

    }  catch (e) {
      print('Exception ${e.toString()}');
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      // client.close();
      // exit(-1);

    }
```

I am looking for a solution or suggestions from the community.

Answer (score 0):

To have this, e.g.: domainname/api/authentication, to this day, the only solution would be to design your own module on Odoo that meets your specifications. Therefore, it's up to you to create a RestApi on Odoo for your project. I found this repository which is probably not up to date [odoo-rest-api](https://github.com/yezyilomo/odoo-rest-api/tree/master), but will give you a good starting point on how to design all of this. Good luck and keep us posted.